# auto generating and replacing a sitemap

Tags: php, mysqli, sitemap

I am trying to automatically replace my sitemap file on the server.  Using php and mysqli, I generate the required output, but I cannot work out how to save that output as a .xml file.
I've read about creating, opening and writing files with php, but I cannot work out how to take my generated content and get it into a file.  Any pointers please?

Here is my code so far...

```html
$my_file = 'sitemap.xml';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
$data=""; //how do I include the code below as my 'data'?

<?php echo"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>"; ?>
<?php 
include "connectScript.php";
$date = date("Y-m-d");
header("Content-type: text/xml");
?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<?php
$baseUrl="mysite.co.uk/page.php";
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT topic FROM db";
$result = $conn->query($query) or die (mysql_error($query));
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$topic = $row['topic'];
$topic = "$baseUrl?t=${topic}";
?>
<url>
<loc>http://www.<?php echo $topic; ?></loc>
<lastmod><?php echo $date; ?></lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
<?php
}
?>
</urlset>

<?php
fwrite($handle, $data);
?>
```

Comment: Post code tried by you to get a response.

Comment: The only pointer is php manual.

Comment: You can either concatenate all of the output in one long string or use the output buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$my_file = 'sitemap.xml';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
$data=""; //how do I include the code below as my 'data'?

<?php ob_start();?>  //start the output buffer

<?php echo"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>"; ?>
<?php 
include "connectScript.php";
$date = date("Y-m-d");
//header("Content-type: text/xml");//remove this, this isn't an xml file it's a php file creating xml
?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<?php
$baseUrl="mysite.co.uk/page.php";
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT topic FROM db";
$result = $conn->query($query) or die (mysql_error($query));
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$topic = $row['topic'];
$topic = "$baseUrl?t=${topic}";
?>
<url>
<loc>http://www.<?php echo $topic; ?></loc>
<lastmod><?php echo $date; ?></lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
<?php
}
?>
</urlset>

<?php
$data = ob_get_clean();  // set everything that was output above to the $data variable
fwrite($handle, $data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to save data to a file, one of the most simple ones being (as quoted from the manual)

```
int file_put_contents ( string $filename , mixed $data [, int $flags = 0 [, resource $context ]] )
```

Which is just a simplified version of fopen/fwrite/fclose. It does however write a string as you had noticed.

### Getting things in a string

#### Option A

Building a string can be done by using:

```
$string = "Hello I'm a string.";
```

To append more you can use

```
$string = $string . " And I'm another part.";
```

Or the shorter version using an [assignment operator](http://php.net/manual/language.operators.assignment.php):

```
$string .= " And I'm another part.";
```

### Option B

It is also possible to buffer any output (things printed (print()/echo/etc.) using [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/function.ob-start.php) like so:

```
ob_start();

echo "Hello i'm a string.";
echo "And I'm another part.";
// do whatever more you need.

$content = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('file.txt', $content);
```

Comment: Thanks WheatBeak, never used output buffer before and your code exactly solved my problem for me.  Thanks again.